# How to import image present in other folder in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, components, assets

The project structure of my app is:-

```
root
|-assets
    |-icons
       |-heart.png

|-components
    |-basic
        |-like.js
```

What i'm trying to achieve is to import image `heart.png` into `like.js` which contains following code:-

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import{ View, Text, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
class Example extends Component {
  render ()
   {
    return(
    <Image src= {require('./assets/icons/heart.png')} />    
    );
 }}

export default Example;
```

It produces following error:-

```
ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir 'C:\Users\gagan\sapora\android\sapora\components\basic\assets\icons'
```

Answer (score 0):

use `source` instead of using `src`

```
render ()
   {
    return(
    <Image source = {require('../assets/icons/heart.png')} />    
    );
 }
```

see here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image

Comment: you need to do '../assets/icons/heart.png' as updated in answer